# LLVM opt cannot find function pass

Tags: c++, llvm

Given the following function pass definition and registration:

```
// STL 
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// LLVM 
#include <llvm/Pass.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instruction.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/IR/CFG.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/IR/InstIterator.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>

// For older versions of llvm you may have to include instead:
// #include "llvm/Support/CFG.h"
// #include <llvm/Support/InstIterator.h>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {

class DefinitionPass  : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;
    DefinitionPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &au) const {
        au.setPreservesAll();
    }

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
            // TODO
            errs() << "def-pass\n";
        return false;
    }
};

class FixingPass : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;
    FixingPass() : FunctionPass(ID){}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
            // TODO
            errs() << "fix-pass\n";
        return true;
    }
};
} // namespace


char DefinitionPass::ID = 0;
char FixingPass::ID = 1;

// Pass registrations
static RegisterPass<DefinitionPass> X("defpass", "Reaching definitions pass");
static RegisterPass<FixingPass> Y("fixpass", "Fixing initialization pass");
```

I compile this given the following makefile. The compilation is successful:

```
CXXFLAGS = -rdynamic $(shell llvm-config --cxxflags) -g -O0 -std=c++0x

all: p34.so

%.so: %.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -dylib -shared -fPIC  $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ *.so
```

Then I create the bitcode file for the file I want to analyse using:

```
clang -O3 -emit-llvm test1.c -c -o test1.bc
```

And use opt in the following way:

```
opt -load p34.so -defpass < test1.bc > /dev/null
```

But opt is unable to find the function pass "defpass":

```
opt: Unknown command line argument '-defpass'.  Try: 'opt --help'
```

I'm on OSX and use the homebrew installed LLVM version.

Does anbody have an idea why opt cannot find the pass?

Answer (score 0):

.so Files are for Linux/Unix. On MAC you should be using p34.dylib

Quoting "https://github.com/banach-space/llvm-tutor"
"Finally, run HelloWorld with opt (use libHelloWorld.so on Linux and libHelloWorld.dylib on Mac OS):"